# C++ Binary into pseudo C++ code. Reverse Engineering

Tags: c++, reverse

How to decompile C++ code from a binary file?

Comment: I have tried few C++ decompilers, but they just did not worked(a lot of code with no sense).

Comment: Well, you usually cannot get anything better than "a lot of code with no sense" without manual intervention, as far as I know (I haven't actually used decompilers myself). If you have a question about a specific problem that you are encoutering trying to modify the decompiler or otherwise programatically trying to achieve what you want, you should post that as a question.

Comment: I was expecting to see if someone here already tried to decompile any c++ linux binary and share their experience. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the machine code generated by modern compilers, particularly for code compiled with at -O1 or higher, bears little resemblance with the original code, it's really not easy to write a tool that does even a reasonable job on this.

I have written my own compiler using LLVM, and just going from LLVM-IR (which is "high level assembler") to machine-code does a lot of changes to the code, especially once some optimisations are enabled. Variables disappear, code belonging to different blocks are mixed together. Assignments moved from their original place to a later place [or earlier].

All loops become "the same" [there is actually a special pass in LLVM to do exactly that, so that later passes can know "what loops look like" and not have to analyse four different ways to make loops [`for`, `while`, `do-while` and `goto`] - they all look very much the same after that pass.

And of course, the compiler will inline functions whenever possible and suitable meaning that what is a nice function inside a class is no longer distinguishable from the other code.

Switch and if-else chains become indistinguishable. In fact, you can see some of that in your example, where a `goto` that is dubious in C++ jumping to L239, when in fact it almost certainly was a switch statement, with a default for the error. It is not very readable, and nearly impossible to change in a meaningful way. And that's still pretty good effort.

Loops are unrolled. Classes and structs stop being objects, and become just a set of distinct variables in some cases.

Casts and conversions disappear and re-appaer somewhere else.

It's just really hard to follow the machine code generated by the compiler and make much sense of it - even harder to reconstruct the original code in any meaningful way.

I'd expect that with some experience, it's easier to read the assembly code and understand what it actually does and recreate the code from that than using a tool that generates "C++" (in some loose sense of the term).